# How can I extract the text part of a blog page while web scraping using beautifulsoup4?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Can anyone help me with the tags that I need to enter so that I can scrape the entire blog from this page: http://suvrobemused.blogspot.in/2018/02/devbhoomi.html?m=1?

```
for link in soupObject.findAll('p'):
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get responses. You can also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

The entire blog is located inside this tag:

```
<div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-7307656586337601982' itemprop='articleBody'>...</div>
```

You can find that tag using this:

```
soup.find('div', class_='post-body entry-content')
```

To get the text inside this tag, you can use `.text` or if you don't want the extra whitespaces, you can use `.get_text(strip=True)`.

```
r = requests.get('http://suvrobemused.blogspot.in/2018/02/devbhoomi.html?m=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
blog_text = soup.find('div', class_='post-body entry-content').text
print(blog_text.strip())
```

Partial output:

> Ever since Pupu grew up, I have been taking advantage of mid-to end
>   February to go travelling. The weather is still fine to tolerable, my
>   work schedule is slack, and it is ‘off-season’ almost everywhere,
>   because millions of kids are taking year-end exams in school, and so
>   their parents are tied up too. I have just come back from another long
>   trip. This one was a repetition in some ways, and a first in some
>   others. I took my mother along with me – for the first time in my
>   life, when I am running fifty five. She was tough enough to cope with
>   the whole thing and enjoy it. Not easy, when I see women half her age
>   – and a lot of men too – who are decrepit already. But then she still
>   teaches mathematics, and insists on doing a lot of the housework…